# Why use RIP-relative addressing in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, memory-address, cpu-registers

I have an assembly hello world program for Mac OS X that looks like this:

```
global _main


section .text

_main:
    mov rax, 0x2000004
    mov rdi, 1
    lea rsi, [rel msg]
    mov rdx, msg.len
    syscall

    mov rax, 0x2000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall


section .data

msg:    db  "Hello, World!", 10
.len:   equ $ - msg
```

I was wondering about the line `lea rsi, [rel msg]`. Why does NASM force me to do that? As I understand it, `msg` is just a pointer to some data in the executable and doing `mov rsi, msg` would put that address into `rsi`. But if I replace the line `lea rsi, [rel msg]` with , NASM throws this error (note: I am using the command `nasm -f macho64 hello.asm`):

```
hello.asm:9: fatal: No section for index 2 offset 0 found
```

Why does this happen? What is so special about `lea` that `mov` can't do? How would I know when to use each one?

Comment: I think Jester already answered this question. The Mach-O object file format requires everything to be position independent. The means your code needs to able to loaded at any address and still work. The `mov rsi, msg` uses an absolute address that would have to change depending on where the program is loaded, and Mach-O doesn't support that.

Comment: @RossRidge But aren't 'absolute addresses' actually relative to the beginning of the executable?

Comment: The CPU doesn't know where the executable starts. When it executes the `mov rsi, msg` instruction it loads the register with the value encoded as an immediate operand. That immediate value needs to be the actual address of `msg`. Mach-O doesn't support that.

Comment: @RossRidge Does the executable know where its going to be loaded? If not, how would it know where the address of  `msg` will be?

Comment: With Mach-O the executable doesn't know where it will be loaded. It doesn't know where `msg` will be located. By using RIP relative addressing it doesn't need to.

Comment: Related: [Why does this MOVSS instruction use RIP-relative addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing) for some explanation of the point of RIP-relative addressing.

Comment: Actually now I am able to use `mov rsi, msg` and it is executing properly. Did the conventions change?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is so special about `lea` that `mov` can't do?

`mov reg,imm` loads an *immediate* constant into its destination operand. Immediate constant is encoded directly in the opcode, e.g. `mov eax,someVar` would be encoded as `B8 EF CD AB 00` if address of `someVar` is `0x00ABCDEF`. I.e. to encode such an instruction with `imm` being address of `msg` you need to know exact address of `msg`. In position-independent code you don't know it a priori.

`mov reg,[expression]` loads the value located at address described by `expression`. The complex encoding scheme of x86 instructions allows to have quite complex `expression`: in general it's `reg1+reg2*s+displ`, where `s` can be 0,1,2,4, `reg1` and `reg2` can be general-purpose registers or zero, and `displ` is immediate displacement. In 64-bit mode `expression` can have one more form: `RIP+displ`, i.e. the address is calculated relative to the next instruction.

`lea reg,[expression]` uses all this complex way of calculating addresses to load *the address itself* into `reg` (unlike `mov`, which dereferences the address calculated). Thus the information, unavailable at compilation time, namely absolute address which would be in `RIP`, can be encoded in the instruction without knowing its value. The nasm expression `lea rsi,[rel msg]` gets translated into something like

```
    lea rsi,[rip+(msg-nextInsn)]
nextInsn:
```

which uses the relative address `msg-nextInsn` instead of absolute address of `msg`, thus allowing the assembler to not know the actual address but still encode the instruction.

Answer (score 12):

> What is so special about lea that mov can't do?

`LEA r, [rel symbol]` can access RIP at run-time.  `mov r, imm` can't.  The immediate constant is encoded into the binary representation of the instruction, which means it won't work if the code+data are mapped to an address that isn't known at link time.  (i.e. it's position-dependent code.)

This is why RIP-relative addressing is so nice for PIC (position-independent code): instead of needing a level of indirection through the Global Offset Table to access even static data defined in the same object file, you can just use RIP-relative addresses.

It also efficiently gives you a 64-bit address without needing a full 64-bit absolute embedded in the instruction.  MacOS X requires 64-bit addresses because it maps the "image base" outside the low 4GiB of virtual address space.

It's a good thing if executables (not just shared libraries) are PIC, so MacOS can randomize their base address for more security.  (Without having to rewrite absolute addresses anywhere they appear.)

---

In position-dependent Linux executables (not MacOS), you can as an optimization use
`mov esi, msg`.  Note ESI, *not* RSI.
`mov rsi, msg` would be *less* efficient, using a 10-byte `mov rsi, imm64` instead of a 7-byte `lea rsi, [RIP + rel32]`.  ([How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register))

The "normal" way to access static data in x86-64 is with RIP-relative addressing, e.g. `mov eax, [rel my_global_var]`. It's only for putting the address into a register that you might sometimes take advantage of 32-bit absolute, if the target allows 32-bit absolute.

Other related Q&As:

- [Why is the address of static variables relative to the Instruction Pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329260/why-is-the-address-of-static-variables-relative-to-the-instruction-pointer)
- [Why are global variables in x86-64 accessed relative to the instruction pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262889/why-are-global-variables-in-x86-64-accessed-relative-to-the-instruction-pointer)
- [Why does this MOVSS instruction use RIP-relative addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing)
- [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)
- [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300844/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm-accessing) )

Comment: update: OS X does support text relocations for 64-bit absolute addresses, but it loads executables outside the low 32 bits so 32-bit absolute addressing is unusable.  Thus RIP-relative addressing isn't *required*, but it's almost always the best option on OS X.