# Weird SSE assembler instructions for double negation

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, sse, magic-numbers

GCC and Clang compilers seem to employ some dark magic. The `C` code just negates the value of a double, but the assembler instructions involve bit-wise `XOR` and the instruction pointer. Can somebody explain what is happening and why is it an optimal solution. Thank you.

Contents of **test.c**:

```
void function(double *a, double *b) {
    *a = -(*b); // This line.
}
```

The resulting assembler instructions:

```
(gcc)
0000000000000000 <function>:
 0: f2 0f 10 06             movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsi]
 4: 66 0f 57 05 00 00 00    xorpd  xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # c <function+0xc>
 b: 00 
 c: f2 0f 11 07             movsd  QWORD PTR [rdi],xmm0
10: c3                      ret
```

---

```
(clang)
0000000000000000 <function>:
 0: f2 0f 10 06             movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsi]
 4: 0f 57 05 00 00 00 00    xorps  xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # b <function+0xb>
 b: 0f 13 07                movlps QWORD PTR [rdi],xmm0
 e: c3                      ret
```

The assembler instruction at address `0x4` represents "This line", however I can't understand how it works. The `xorpd/xorps` instructions are supposed to be bit-wise `XOR` and `PTR [rip]` is the instruction pointer.

I suspect that at the moment of execution `rip` is pointing somewhere near the `0f 57 05 00 00 00 0f` strip of bytes, but I can't quite figure out, how is this working and why do both compilers choose this approach.

P.S. I should point out that this is compiled using `-O3`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Both compilers XOR with a constant representing -0.0, which they load from memory. That makes sense for [RIP-relative offsetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing/44967386#44967386). What doesn't make sense is that your disassembly shows them loading the bytes of the next instruction as the floating-point constant. That cannot be right. Is it possible that you somehow stripped an offset from the disassembly? Or that your disassembler is confused?

Comment: I am definitely not changing anything manually. With the above code verbatim and the commands `gcc test.c -c -O3 -o test.o` and `objdump -S -M intel test.o` this is the output I get. I will reiterate that I know what `PTR [rip]` is and that you can invert the sign by changing the leading bit in a double. The reason I am asking is because the two ideas don't mix in my head.

Comment: The more you are sure that you didn't make a mistake, the more likely you did. Copied the wrong part from console. Sorry the assembler listing should be the right one now. The strange `xor` with `rip` is still there though.

Comment: This looks like unlinked code, where offsets are not fixed up yet. Hence the `[rip + 0x0]`part. This is RIP-relative addressing alright, but the offset was not put in place by a linker yet. See the accepted answer, which obviously uses properly linked code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for me the output of `gcc` with the `-S -O3` options for the same code is:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  function
    .type   function, @function
function:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movsd   (%rsi), %xmm0
    xorpd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rdi)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   function, .-function
    .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .align 16
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   -2147483648
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

here the `xorpd` instruction uses instruction pointer relative addressing with the offset which points to `.LC0` label with the 64 bit value `0x8000000000000000`(the 63rd bit is set to one).

```
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   -2147483648
```

if your compiler was big endian these lines where swaped.

xoring the double value with `0x8000000000000000` sets the sign bit(which is the 63rd bit) to one for a negative value.

clang uses `xorps` instruction for the same manner this xors the first 32bit of the double value.

if you run object dump with `-r` option it will show you the relocations that should be done on the program before running it.

`objdump -d test.o -r`

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <function>:
   0:   f2 0f 10 06             movsd  (%rsi),%xmm0
   4:   66 0f 57 05 00 00 00    xorpd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # c <function+0xc>
   b:   00 
            8: R_X86_64_PC32    .LC0-0x4
   c:   f2 0f 11 07             movsd  %xmm0,(%rdi)
  10:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   2:   c3                      retq
```

here at `<function + 0xb>` we have a relocation of type R_X86_64_PC32.

PS: I'm using gcc 6.3.0

Comment: Correct, but not the 0th bit is set to one, the 63rd bit (the sign bit) is set to one, hence the hex value 0x8000000000000000.

Answer (score 4):

> `xorps  xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x0]`

Any part of an instruction surrounded by `[]` is an indirect reference to memory. 
In this case a reference to the memory at address `RIP+0`
*(I doubt it is actually `RIP+0`, you might have edited the actual offset)*

The X64 instruction set adds [instruction pointer relative addressing](http://www.codegurus.be/Programming/riprelativeaddressing_en.htm). This means you can have (usually read-only) data in your program that you can address easily even if the program is moved around in memory.

A `XOR xmm0,Y` inverts all bits in xmm0 that are set in `Y`.
Negation involves inverting the sign bit, so that's why xor is used. Specifically `xorpd/s` because we are dealing with double resp. single floats.

Comment: I am quite sure that I am not changing anything manually. Maybe, you can post the output you are getting so I can try to compare.

Comment: @RuRo, you probably did not run `objdump` with the `--reloc` option.  Then you get the raw instructions without the relocations which will be used to rewrite some of the arguments prior to execution.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Damn. You're right. I just assumed that there are no relocations, since there is nothing to link. Our professor would be mad if he knew. We totally learned that in class.

Comment: @RuRo: I like `alias disas='objdump -drwC -Mintel'`