# Calculation of relative offset in small code model

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, abi, relocation

I am trying to understand the RIP relative offset used in small-code model. Perhaps the only approachable resource on the internet on this topic is: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models
But in this post also a few things are not clear.
I am using this simple program to understand a few things:

```
// sample.cc
int arr[10] = {0};
int arr_big[100000] = {0};
int arr2[500] = {0};
int main() {
  int t = 0;
  t += arr[7];
  t +=arr_big[6];
  t += arr2[10];
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation: `g++ -c sample.cc -o sample.o`

Object code for .text section:(`objdump -dS sample.o`)

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   b:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 11 <main+0x11>
  11:   01 45 fc                add    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  14:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 1a <main+0x1a>
  1a:   01 45 fc                add    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  1d:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 23 <main+0x23>
  23:   01 45 fc                add    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  26:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  2b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  2c:   c3                      ret
```

Relocation table: (`readelf -r sample.o`)

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x1a8 contains 3 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000000000d  000300000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 arr + 18
000000000016  000400000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000040 arr_big + 14
00000000001f  000500000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000061ac0 arr2 + 24
```

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33690144/8349044) what I understand is, offset is the first byte of text section that has to be modified. Compiler does not know the position of any relocatable entry in advance, that's why it creates the sections filled with `00` which will be populated by the linker.
This explanation is understandable once we look at the `objdump` output. The first relocation has offset `0xd` and the "d-th" byte in .text is the section containing 0s in this line `8b 05 00 00 00 00`.

So, linker will fill the address of `arr` in this position. `R_X86_64_PC32` means "take the symbol value, add the addend and subtract the offset". I am not understanding this calculation. What do they mean by "symbol value"?
In small code model all offsets will be relative to instruction pointer (RIP). So, for the line `mov 0x0(%rip),%eax`, the RIP value will be next instruction address (`0x11`). Offset is `0xd` and addend is `0x18`. So, if we add the addend to RIP and subtract offset (`0x11 + 0x18 - 0xd`) it becomes `0x1c` which is 7th integer (1 int = 4 bytes). It makes sense, because that instruction is trying to access 7th index in array `arr`. What I don't understand is:

1. How is the relative offset between RIP and `arr` calculated. Is it something calculated by linker at linking time?
2. Why does it need to be 32 bit?
3. What does sym. value signify in relocation table? I am assuming it is the relative position of the symbols in their sections. E.g. `arr` has sym value `0` as it is the first entry in .bss section. `arr_big` has `40` as sym. value as it is the second entry after 40 bytes long `arr` and `arr2` has `0x61ac0` as sym. value as it comes after arr_big and arr (40 + 100000 bytes).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that most modern distros configure GCC to use `-fPIE -pie` by default, so you're targeting the small-PIE code-model unless you use `-fno-pie` for code-gen and `-no-pie` for linking, then you truly have the traditional "small" code model.  (See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427))

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for bringing this up. I noticed this. I usually compile with -fno-PIC and that generates rip relative relocations.

Comment: Compilers will always use `mov foo(%rip), %eax` to load a global. ([Why does this MOVSS instruction use RIP-relative addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44967075)).  The main difference is in putting the address of a global into a register ([How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)), or in runtime-variable indexing of global arrays. (And in generating jump tables for `switch` statements.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linker stores sections to memory starting with image base absolute address, say 0x0040_0000. Section **.text** is stored at 0x0040_1000 and **.data**  at 0x0040_2000.
The value of symbol **main** is at offset 0 in section **.text**, which is then 0x0040_1000.
The value of symbol **arr** is at offset 0 in section **.data**, which is 0x0040_2000.
Only then are the relocations being resolved.

`Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend`
`00000000000d  000300000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 arr + 18`

Relocation.Info (2) tells that its type is *Program Counter relative 32bit field relocation* in **.text** section at offset 0xd, so its absolute virtual address (VA) is 0x0040_100d.

Relocation.Info (3) tells that it is related to the 3rd item in the symbol table, which represents **.data** section with VA 0x0040_2000.

With knowledge of the final addresses of all symbols the linker can now perform the calculations.
In the statement mentioned above
`b:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 11 <main+0x11>`
it takes the target symbol **arr** VA 0x0040_2000, subtracts the field offset 0x0040_100d, adds the addend 0x18 and the result 0x100B is then added to whatever was emitted by compiler to the instruction body (to the value 0x00000000).
CPU will see the statement `mov 0x0(%rip),%eax` as `b:   8b 05 0b 10 00 00`, as you could see in debugger. RIP of this instruction is 0x0040_1011 and when you add the 32bit imm value 0x100b to RIP, register EAX will be loaded from VA 0x0040_201c, which is the 7th DWORD of **arr**.

> 3. What does sym. value signify in relocation table?

This is information calculated from target value+addend by *readelf* for your convenience, in fact it is contained in relocation record only indirectly as the high dword of Rela.Info. in the form of ordinal number into symbol table.