# SIGSEGV on x86/x64 due to conflict between raw memory access and DS register in C compiled with TCC as JIT engine on Linux

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, memory-segmentation, tcc

First, I know this is kind of **unholy** thing but I attempts to reduce instructions overhead in jitted **C** code with **TCC** by replacing some dereference with well-known constant memory location to evaluate possible performance gain. As I doesn't know a lot about **x86/x64** memory segmentation, this issue may be perhaps impossible to fix or be a **TCC** compiler limitation.

In short version, this code:

```c
// Two 64 bits integer
U64 a, b;

// ADD_CODE is just a macro to add C source that will be compiled
ADD_CODE("if ((*((volatile U64*)(%p)) += %d) >= *((volatile U64*)(%p))) {\n", &a, 1, &b);
```

Lead me to this assembly (which segfaults (**SIGSEGV**) due to bad address):

```
    0x1a6ac56 movabs rax, 0x7ffff5e1b020
    0x1a6ac60 mov    rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
    0x1a6ac63 add    rax, 0x1
 →  0x1a6ac67 mov    QWORD PTR ds:0xfffffffff5e1b020, rax
    0x1a6ac6f movabs rcx, 0x7ffff5e1b028
```

The **a** & **b** variables are of a part of a **C++** object instance which is there before any compilation and remains in place when the jitted code is executed. We can see that the **a** variable is located at **0x7ffff5e1b020** and I can indeed access this variable at this address through GDB.

But for a reason outside of my current knowledge base, the writeback of this variable seems to implies **DS** register and the memory address now looks like a kernel space address which produces the **SIGSEGV**.

My guess tends toward a limitations of **TCC** on the writeback of a direct memory access with an incrementation (this increment isn't always 1 outside of example). I was surprise that **TCC** didn't rewrote the address in another register than **RAX**, at least for writeback.

Following research about **DS**, I tried to add a volatile keyword in the cast but without any difference in generated assembly. I also tried to get the increment operation outside of the "if" statement but again assembly remains the same.

Is there anybody with a suggestion to try? Maybe there is a keyword or something that specify targeted memory space for this kind of access? (I guess it may happens when accessing IO, but there isn't as much OS magic barrier in this case)

Comment: It looks like you truncated a pointer to 32-bit and let it get sign-extended to 64.  Looks like with a `[disp32]` addressing mode, since that's a `mov` not a `movabs`.  You normally want RIP-relative addressing modes for static storage, like `mov rax, [RIP + rel32]` because that's a 7-byte instruction, not 10 for `movabs`, and fits in the uop cache more efficiently.

Comment: Please add the `ADD_CODE` macro to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you (or TCC) truncated a pointer to 32-bit and let it get sign-extended to 64.  It used a `[disp32]` addressing mode for the store, since that's a `mov` not `movabs moffs, rax`.

64-bit mode implies that CS/DS/ES/SS segment bases are all zero, and 32-bit code under mainstream OSes already did that. `ds:0x...` is how GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` disassembly syntax (like `objdump -drwC -Mintel`) shows `[disp32]` addressing modes to distinguish them from immediates, instead of just using square brackets (which do work in asm source around bare numbers, unlike in actual MASM). e.g. `add rax, 1` adds a constant `1`, not a load from absolute address `1`.

`movabs rax, 0x7ffff5e1b020` is a mov-immediate of the address, and `mov rax, [rax]` uses DS as the segment base, too, it just doesn't show it in disassembly.

---

Note that TCC is old, and x86-64 support was probably added after it was designed to compile for 32-bit x86.  **This is probably a TCC bug**, if that code (before the `mov rcx`) all comes from the `*((volatile uint64_t*)(0x7ffff5e1b020) += 1`, since it loads from the right address but truncates the store address.  32-bit x86 could use any valid address as an absolute addressing mode.  x86-64 can only do that for loads/store of the accumulator, with the `mov moffs` aka `movabs` opcodes (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov).

---

You normally want RIP-relative addressing modes for static storage, like `mov rax, [RIP + rel32]` because that's a 7-byte instruction, not 10 for movabs, and fits in the uop cache more efficiently.  (Or a RIP-relative `lea` into a different register so it can reuse the address between the load and store, while still leaving the `+=` result in a register for compare as part of the same expression.)

TCC is using the worst possible strategy, `mov` a 64-bit immediate into a register then `mov rax, [rax]` to overwrite the address with the value.  But it needs to store the `+=` back to the same address, so if it had just used any of the other registers, it would still have the address available for `mov [rdx], rax` or whatever.  To make correct code, it would need another `movabs rcx, imm64` to re-materialize the address in a register before `mov [rcx], rax` or something.

Or since this is the accumulator, `movabs rax, ds:0x7ffff5e1b020` / `inc rax` / `movabs ds:0x7ffff5e1b020, rax` would be encodeable.  (mov-imm64 into any register is available, but load/store from a 64-bit absolute address is only for AL/AX/EAX/RAX.  But this is TCC so it's not going to look for the RAX special case.)

IDK why it knows how to `mov-imm64` into a register for loads but not for stores.  Perhaps since the load doesn't need any extra registers, because it's already a load into a register so that register can work as scratch space for the address.  Truncating 64-bit addresses for stores is obviously a problem.

Non-PIE executables have their static storage in the low 32 bits of virtual address-space where `mov [disp32], reg` can address it, but `mov [RIP+rel32]` is still more efficient, which is why mainstream compilers like GCC and clang use RIP-relative addressing for global / static variables even in non-PIE executables.  *[Why does this MOVSS instruction use RIP-relative addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing)*  (But `mov r32, imm32` for static addresses in non-PIEs vs. RIP-relative LEA in PIE or other shared objects.  *[How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register)*)

BTW, it's probably going to make the same inefficient mess for the other side of the `<=` comparison where you have a similar expression.  That is just a load, but in your case the address of `b` is very near the address of `a` so good code-gen that put the address into a register once for the `+=` could use that with a small offset, like

```
    movabs rcx, 0x7ffff5e1b020
    mov    rax, [rcx]
    add    rax, 0x1
    mov    [rcx], rax
    cmp    rax, [rcx+8]      # 0x7ffff5e1b020+8 = 0x7ffff5e1b028
```

That's one inefficient 10-byte instruction, the rest are 3 or 4 bytes each.

---

If you're using TCC as a JIT with literal 64-bit constants for addresses (printf `%p` with `&a` to make C for TCC to compile into a library which you dlopen), it's not going to be able to use RIP-relative addressing.  Using a local var like `uint64_t *anchor = 0x7ffff5e1b020;` would give you a reference point for your global vars with a +- 2GiB range.  (Or `char*` or `uint32_t*` and cast it after pointer math.)  e.g. `anchor[1]` is `b` in your case if you defined it as `uint64_t*`.

TCC will probably have to load that from the stack at least once in every expression that uses it, but `mov rax, [rbp+8]` is only 4 bytes long and can run efficiently on existing CPUs.  (2 loads per clock cycle, or 3 on Alder Lake, and Zen 3 and later for scalar-integer loads.)  If the alternative was `movabs r64, imm64`, that probably better even though `movabs`-imm64 can run on any ALU port instead of a lot.

I'm hoping TCC will load that pointer local var into a register and then use addressing modes like `[rcx]` or `[rcx+8]` when the C source looks like `anchor[0]` or `anchor[1]`, but if it wastes instructions on `add` then it might be worse.

Comment: This attempts was only to demonstrate "easy to integrate" small improvement by reducing dereference in TCC to avoid direct assembly writing unless unavoidable, but your detailed answer are really interesting of how small this code could be.

Answer (score 1):

It work with an anchor as you proposed, I can get it initialized earlier and it result in a 2.5% speed improvement in our specific use case. Thus for anyone that may be looking for the same gain in memory access without maintaining assembly code, it can be an interesting trade-off.

As you said, I think it's a bug in **TCC** or at least something make it drop the cast. I tried to separate the increment statement, or use complete expression to bias TCC but none worked.

```
// Only increment - Not working
ADD_CODE("*((volatile U64*)(%p)) += 1UL;\n", &a);
```

---

```
// Complete expression - Not working
// Surprisingly it generates the exact same assembly, I was expecting TCC 
// to consider both pointer as separate variable
ADD_CODE("*((volatile U64*)(%p)) = 1UL + *((volatile U64*)(%p));\n", &a, &a);
```

---

```
// Temporary variable - Not working
ADD_CODE("U64 foo = 1UL + *((volatile U64*)(%p));\n", &a);
ADD_CODE("*((volatile U64*)(%p)) = foo;\n", &a);

// At this point, it's clear for me 
0x1abbcd9      movabs rax, 0x7ffff5e1b020                    → Load &a in RAX
0x1abbce3      mov    rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
0x1abbce6      add    rax, 0x1
0x1abbcea      mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x60], rax              → Write to foo
0x1abbcee      mov    rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-0x60]              → Read again from foo (TCC...)
0x1abbcf2      mov    QWORD PTR ds:0xfffffffff5e1b020, rax   → SIGSEGV
0x1abbcfa      movabs rax, 0x7ffff5e1b020
0x1abbd04      mov    rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
0x1abbd07      movabs rcx, 0x7ffff5e1b028
0x1abbd11      mov    rcx, QWORD PTR [rcx]
0x1abbd14      cmp    rax, rcx
```

---

So in conclusion, only explicit pointer such as your example with **anchor** seems to work with TCC.

Comment: If `volatile` was just a failed attempt to work around this TCC pointer-truncation bug, you should remove it.  IDK if it would lead to any improvement in the code-gen since it's not an optimizing compiler anyway, but your use-case doesn't need it unless you're multi-threading.  (In which case `volatile` is normally the wrong tool for the job, except on compilers without support for `_Atomic`.  `volatile` is basically like atomic with `memory_order_relaxed` in some compilers.  And TCC is sort of like a portable assembler in some ways since it's known to be non-optimizing.)