# ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, ld

This is the error I'm getting while doing a code on assembly language in Linux Ubuntu. Can anyone help me resolve the error?

This is the error that's coming when I use the command `ld -o quadratic quadratic.o`

[The image of Error that's coming.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMDf9.png)

the code to my asm file is this:

https://github.com/vedantdawange/ASM-Files/blob/main/quadratic.asm

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning.  That's why you can assemble+link a `.asm` containing just a single instruction you want to single-step in a debugger.  Like `cat > foo.asm` / `mov rax, 1234` / control-d / nasm / ld / gdb ./a.out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ld` by itself links no libraries or startup code.  It's suitable for a program where you use `_start` as an entry point and do I/O via direct calls to the kernel instead of standard C library functions.  But your program uses `main` as its entry point, so it expects to be called by C startup code, and it calls library functions like `printf`.  Hence you should link it like a C program:

```
gcc -no-pie -o quadratic quadratic.o
```

The `-no-pie` option is needed because your code makes absolute references to static data, e.g. `fld qword[b]`.  gcc by default assumes you want to build a position-independent executable, which can't do that; you'd need to write `fld qword[rel b]` to produce an rip-relative effective address.  So `-no-pie` asks gcc to link a non-position-independent executable. See [Why use RIP-relative addressing in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234395/why-use-rip-relative-addressing-in-nasm/36952302#36952302) for more on this.

Comment: Still dosent seem to work. This error is coming 

relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Perhaps `default rel` (before any of the memory accesses) would help.

Comment: @VEDANTDAWANGE: You need `-no-pie` for your code as it stands.  See edit.

Comment: Thank you! gcc -no-pie -o quadratic quadratic.o works! You are a lifesaver. Thank you so much.

Comment: @VEDANTDAWANGE: You should always use `default rel`; RIP-relative access is more efficient.  You might need `-no-pie` anyway, though, if you call any library functions without manually indirecting through the PLT or GOT.  Also, normally there's not much reason to use legacy x87 for floating point on x86-64; SSE2 for `movsd` / `addsd` etc. is guaranteed to be available.  x87 is mostly only useful when you *need* more precision than 64-bit double, but 80-bit x87 is enough.

Comment: @ecm: Surprisingly, `default rel` affects memory references that appear before it, at least last I checked.  IDK if that's intended or a NASM bug, but you can put it at the end of a file.