# Syntax for indirect jump in GAS (Intel syntax): double brackets and/or OFFSET as part of the addressing mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, addressing-mode, intel-syntax

For an indirect jump to the address stored in `L + 8` in 64-bit mode,

`nasm` accepts,

```
jmp [L + 8]
jmp qword [L + 8]
```

GNU `as` accepts,

```
jmp [L + 8]
jmp qword ptr [L + 8]
```

and also,

```
jmp [[L + 8]]
jmp [qword ptr [L + 8]]
```

even more,

```
jmp qword ptr [offset L + 8]
jmp [qword ptr [offset L + 8]]
```

but not,

```
jmp [offset L + 8]
jmp [[offset L + 8]]
```

I'm very confused about what effects the brackets, `qword ptr` and `offset` are having in those statements.

I know the basics that GAS treats `L` as same as `[L]`, and you have to put `offset` to use `L` as a constant memory address, but this doesn't explain why sometimes it's okay to omit `offset` and sometimes you must omit `offset`, and why it is okay to put additional brackets.

Could you clarify the syntax used for indirect jumps in GAS Intel syntax?

Comment: The fact that GAS accepts some crazy syntax is just a side effect of a less-than-perfect parser. Do not use double brackets, or the `offset` keyword. In any case, use a disassembler if you are curious what the assembler emits for the crazy forms.

Comment: Should be no different from addressing modes in other contexts, like `mov rcx, [L + 8]`.  (Note that you should use `[RIP + L + 8]` because RIP-relative addressing is more efficient than absolute, even when absolute is possible.)

Comment: oh, I guess there is one difference: `jmp L` would be a different instruction, so you do always need brackets or something else to disambiguate from a relative direct jump.  But otherwise it's just a normal addressing mode, I think.  As Jester says, GAS's parser is not very strict.  e.g. `mov $'abcd', %eax` breaks the parser in interesting and exciting ways, instead of working anything like NASM `mov eax, 'abcd'`.  It seems GAS only cares about the opening quote, not a close quote.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm a bit confused by your comment about relative addressing. Is it still more efficient when I'm not compiling to a PIE executable? Also with relative addressing I have to put additional `lea`s to add a variable index.

Comment: `[RIP + rel32]` is more efficient than `[disp32]` with no GP registers.  If you want to use it with a GP register, `[base + disp32]` is just as efficient, and of course saves an LEA.  I meant using relative addressing for access to static storage, not writing fully position-independent code.  See [Why are global variables in x86-64 accessed relative to the instruction pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56262889) / [Why use RIP-relative addressing in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34034877) / [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)