# x86 assembly for 64-bit, returning a string from a function and placing it into an array

Tags: function, file, assembly, x86, x86-64

I am using 64-bit assembly and have two different files. One of the files changes the string so that the string has random new characters added. The other file contains an array .

This is from the file which edits the string:

```
    returnString:
        mov rax, newString
        ret
```

This is the array and how it is set up:

```
section .bss
    array: resq 4
    allocString: resb 128

section .text
_start:
   mov qword[array], defaultMes0
        xor r8,r8
        add r8, 8

        mov qword[array + r8], defaultMes1
        add r8, 8

        mov qword[array + r8], defaultMes2
        add r8, 8

        mov qword[array + r8], defaultMes3
        add r8, 8
```

This is the function which is supposed to move the string from the function into the array:

```
rev:

        mov rax, 8
        movzx rdx, byte [index] ; Clear rdx to avoid issues with imul

        imul rdx ; Multiply index by 8

        mov rdi, qword [array + rax]

        call stringEdit

        lea rbx, [allocString]
        
        translateLoop:
            mov dl, [rax]
            mov [rbx], dl

            ;both incremented and counter also incremented
            inc rax
            inc rbx

            ;comparison, if less than bl then done until it is equal to enterNum (place of split)
            cmp byte[rax], 0x0
            jne translateLoop
        
        mov rax, 8
        movzx rdx, byte [index] ; Clear rdx again

        imul rdx ; Multiply index by 8

        mov qword [array + rax], rbx
```

If you output the string using a print function, it will be blank (e.g. it will output nothing).

I've tried doing:

```
    returnString:
        mov rax, [newString]
        ret
```

but it does not work properly. I've also tried to directly place the output from the function into the string like below, but that also does not work (both when newString is referenced or dereferenced). This results in a seg fault when printed if newString is dereferenced, and if not referenced, any other time the function is called, everything in the array points to the same thing, thus any array index which has this function called will share the same result.

```
call stringEdit

mov qword [array + rax], rdi ;;moved it to the rdi before
```

Comment: Hard to figure out what you want and what the problem is. Create a [mcve] by reducing the code to e.g. one file that returns a new string and another that just changes a single character.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried doing
>
> ```
> returnString:
>     mov rax, [newString]
>     ret
> ```

This would return the first eight bytes from the new string's content. Your first attempt was correct with `mov rax, newString` returning the address of the new string.

---

> ```
> mov qword[array], defaultMes0
> xor r8,r8
> add r8, 8
> mov qword[array + r8], defaultMes1
> add r8, 8
> mov qword[array + r8], defaultMes2
> add r8, 8
> mov qword[array + r8], defaultMes3
> add r8, 8
> ```

You [can't move a 64-bit immediate to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771323/why-we-cant-move-a-64-bit-immediate-value-to-memory?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C149.6502) and the use of R8 is over-complicating since you can more easily offset with `+8`, `+16`, and `+24`.

```
lea  rax, [rel defaultMes0]
mov  [rel array], rax
lea  rax, [rel defaultMes1]
mov  [rel array + 8], rax
lea  rax, [rel defaultMes2]
mov  [rel array + 16], rax
lea  rax, [rel defaultMes3]
mov  [rel array + 24], rax
```

[Info about RIP relative addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234395/why-use-rip-relative-addressing-in-nasm?r=SearchResults&s=12%7C69.0831).

---

> ```
> mov rax, 8
> movzx rdx, byte [index] ; Clear rdx to avoid issues with imul
> imul rdx ; Multiply index by 8
> mov rdi, qword [array + rax]
> ```

For reading and writing based on your *index* variable [0,3], instead of a separate multiplication by 8, better use a scaled-index addressing mode:

```
movzx ecx, byte [index]      ; Load RCX with index [0,3]
mov   rdi, [array + rcx * 8]
```

---

> ```
>   lea rbx, [allocString]
> translateLoop:
>   mov dl, [rax]
>   mov [rbx], dl
>   inc rax
>   inc rbx
>   cmp byte[rax], 0x0
>   jne translateLoop
>   mov rax, 8
>   movzx rdx, byte [index]
>   imul rdx
>   mov qword [array + rax], rbx   ; (*)
> ```

A number of errors here:

- you expect the source string to never by empty
- you don't copy the zero-terminator and thus the destination string will not be zero-terminated
- you erroneously (*) copy RBX to the array of pointers when RBX is pointing to the end of the new string, in other words: store RBX **before** using it in the copy loop.

```
    call  stringEdit             ; -> RAX
    lea   rbx, [rel allocString]
    movzx ecx, byte [index]      ; Load RCX with index [0,3]
    mov   [array + rcx * 8], rbx
copyLoop:
    movzx edx, byte [rax]
    mov   [rbx], dl
    inc   rax
    inc   rbx
    cmp   byte [rax - 1], 0
    jne   copyLoop
```

> If you output the string using a print function, it will be blank (e.g. it will output nothing).

(*) Is what you'd expect when the address points behind the string.